# Why is the Japanese title of Dante's "Divine Comedy" 『神曲』?

Tags: translation, literature

Dante's *The Divine Comedy* (whose English title appears to basically be the same as the original Italian title, *Divina Commedia*) is titled in Japanese 『神曲』. Why is this? Naturally, translations need not be literal, but a title meaning roughly "The Divine Song" (or "The Divine Poem"?) seems a bit odd when something along the lines of 「神喜劇」 could've been done.

I read the section 題名『神曲』の由来 in [the Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A5%9E%E6%9B%B2#.E9.A1.8C.E5.90.8D.E3.80.8E.E7.A5.9E.E6.9B.B2.E3.80.8F.E3.81.AE.E7.94.B1.E6.9D.A5), which indicates that Mori Ougai's translation of Hans Christian Andersen's novel *The Improvisatore* contains the passage 「神曲、吾友なる貴公子」 and Mori's choice of 『神曲』 stuck. That explains the history of it; so my question is really more, why might Mori have chosen this translation? Did 曲 mean something closer to "comedy" at the time he wrote it (c. 1902)?

Comment: I'm not sure why he choose this translation, but I think that 曲, although is usually used to indicate a musical composition, indicates another types of compositions as well, apparently teatrical ones. You can read for example 曲 as くせ (long segment of a [noh play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noh) forming its musical highlight), and find words as 戯曲{ぎきょく} (play;  drama).

Comment: そもそもダンテの時代の "commedia" と、現代英語の "comedy" の意味合い自体が違っているので、そのあたりの下調べなく、フツーの英語話者の感覚のみで質問している気がしてなりません。やや残念です。

Comment: @l'électeur I agree that "commedia" in Dante's Italian wouldn't match the most common modern English sense for "comedy", but the classical sense of "comedy" (which I assume is close to Dante's sense) is still understood by well-read English-speakers. My mistake was in thinking that the same "classical" sense was present in 喜劇, but apparently it is not, as naruto's answer indicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WIkipediaによれば元来のcomedyは以下のようなものであり、単に形式的なもののようです。

> ただしコメディ（Comedy）の西洋における元義は、悲劇（英: Tragedy ）の対照を成す意味での演劇である（例えばギリシア悲劇に対するギリシア喜劇）。従って本来は必ずしも笑えるものだけを意味するとは限らない。 例えば、ダンテの『神曲』も原題は「羅: La Divina Commedia 」であり、日本語で通常の直訳では「神聖な（もしくは神の）喜劇」となるが、笑えるものを意味しているわけではない。

対照的に、「喜劇」という日本語は comedy の訳語ではありますが、ほぼ常に「お笑い」を主体とするものを指します。「喜劇」という言葉は作品の性質に合わず、誤解を招く危険があるため、森鴎外も敢えて訳さなかったのでは、と推測します。

ちなみに、「神喜劇」だと大抵の現代人は[吉本新喜劇](http://www.yoshimoto.co.jp/shinkigeki/)を連想してしまいそうです。

参考

- https://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q1432780539